# Nonclustered index include column causes high fragmentation

Tags: sql-server, indexing, azure-sql-database

I have a nonclustered index in Azure SQL Server as follows:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_index_xx] 
ON [dbo].[ActiveDay] ([user_id] ASC, [enterprise_id] ASC)
INCLUDE ([dateTime])  
WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When application is running, it can enter new rows to this table or update the "dateTime" column when user perform some operations like login. There is no other  heavy operations in this table. I have around 135,000 rows in the table. I rebuilt the above index, but after 1 day it becomes fragmented again with 60% with page count around 1370. Why it is getting highly fragmented within 1 day? I really don't understand the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why it is getting highly fragmented within 1 day?

The rows in this index are sorted by (user_id,enterprise_id).  So when you insert a new row in the table it may go in the *end* of the clustered index, but it must be inserted into the *middle* of this nonclustered index.  If the target page is full, it must be split, and a new page will be started on a non-full extent for this database.

The interleaving of extents from different objects, and the interleaving of pages from different parts of the index sort order are both types of fragmentation. This kind of fragmentation of non-clustered index is normal, and typically not a significant issue, especially if your database is stored on SSDs, as all Azure SQL Databases are.

After you rebuild the index, all the leaf pages in the index are 100% full, and the fragmentation is mostly eliminated.  But as you insert new rows into the table the fragmentation will naturally return. Right after the rebuild any insert will require a page split, and lead to some fragmentation.  If you really want to rebuild the index you can set a fill factor of 80% or so to prevent a flurry of page splits after the index rebuild.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the info. I was always under the impression that if fragmentation of some clustered indexes are like 97%, then it really slows down some queries. I had situations that some queries take like 6 mins to return and once I rebuild these non-clustered indexes, they return in like 3 seconds. So if I can't rely on this fragmentation % totally, how can I use this fragmentation information in non-clustered indexes?

Comment: Rebuilding an index _also_ updates statistics, and that can affect the query plan chosen.  In Azure SQL Database it's safe to ignore and rely on automatic tuning, at least initially.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automatic-tuning-enable